# Wordpress Theme development - WP standard CSS classes are unknown

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

i created a wordpress theme including an own style.css file in the themes folder. When i use the theme nearly everything works as expected except the wordpress own standard classes. For example: If i select an image with the WP image tool and select "align: center" it adds the class "aligncenter" automatically to the image. But this class will not be found by the website. How can i ensure that those standard CSS classes are valid besides my own style.css of my theme?

Thanks.

Comment: Load that .css file with your own styles..

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add the rules yourself, you could copy what you need from e.g. TwentyTwelve: http://themes.svn.wordpress.org/twentytwelve/1.1.1/style.css

Also, take a look at this article, listing all relevant selectors: http://digwp.com/2010/05/default-wordpress-css-styles-hooks/

Comment: Thanks. I found this, and this is really helpful: http://codex.wordpress.org/CSS#WordPress_Generated_Classes

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the standard WordPress Css into your main stylesheet- which can be found here

http://codex.wordpress.org/CSS#WordPress_Generated_Classes